# Good practice to validate immutable values objects

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, validation

Suppose a MailConfiguration class specifying settings for sending mails :

```
public class MailConfiguration {

  private AddressesPart addressesPart;

  private String subject;

  private FilesAttachments filesAttachments;

  private String bodyPart;

  public MailConfiguration(AddressesPart addressesPart, String subject, FilesAttachments filesAttachements,
    String bodyPart) {
    Validate.notNull(addressesPart, "addressesPart must not be null");
    Validate.notNull(subject, "subject must not be null");
    Validate.notNull(filesAttachments, "filesAttachments must not be null");
    Validate.notNull(bodyPart, "bodyPart must not be null");
    this.addressesPart = addressesPart;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.filesAttachements = filesAttachements;
    this.bodyPart = bodyPart;
  }
  // ...  some useful getters ......

}
```

**So, I'm using two values objects :  AddressesPart and FilesAttachment.**

Theses two values objects have similar structures so I'm only going to expose here AddressesPart :

```
public class AddressesPart {

  private final String senderAddress;

  private final Set recipientToMailAddresses;

  private final Set recipientCCMailAdresses;

  public AddressesPart(String senderAddress, Set recipientToMailAddresses, Set recipientCCMailAdresses) {
    validate(senderAddress, recipientToMailAddresses, recipientCCMailAdresses);
    this.senderAddress = senderAddress;
    this.recipientToMailAddresses = recipientToMailAddresses;
    this.recipientCCMailAdresses = recipientCCMailAdresses;
  }

  private void validate(String senderAddress, Set recipientToMailAddresses, Set recipientCCMailAdresses) {
    AddressValidator addressValidator = new AddressValidator();
    addressValidator.validate(senderAddress);
    addressValidator.validate(recipientToMailAddresses);
    addressValidator.validate(recipientCCMailAdresses);
  }

  public String getSenderAddress() {
    return senderAddress;
  }

  public Set getRecipientToMailAddresses() {
    return recipientToMailAddresses;
  }

  public Set getRecipientCCMailAdresses() {
    return recipientCCMailAdresses;
  }

}
```

**And the associated validator : AddressValidator**

```
public class AddressValidator {

  private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN
    = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

  public void validate(String address) {
    validate(Collections.singleton(address));
  }

  public void validate(Set addresses) {
    Validate.notNull(addresses, "List of mail addresses must not be null");
    for (Iterator it = addresses.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
      String address = (String) it.next();
      Validate.isTrue(address != null && isAddressWellFormed(address), "Invalid Mail address " + address);
    }
  }

  private boolean isAddressWellFormed(String address) {
    Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = emailPattern.matcher(address);
    return matcher.matches();
  }
}
```

Thus, I have two questions :

1) If for some reasons, later, we want to validate differently an address mail (for instance to include/exclude some aliases matching to existing mailingList), should I expose a kind of IValidator as a constructor parameter ? like the following rather than bringing concrete dependence (like I made):

```
public AddressValidator(IValidator myValidator) {
   this.validator = myValidator;
}
```

Indeed, this will respect the D principle of SOLID principle : Dependency injection.

However, if we follow this logical, would a majority of Values Objects own an abstract validator or it's just an overkill the most of time (thinking to YAGNI ?) ?

2) I've read in some articles than in respect of DDD, all validations must be present and only present in Aggregate Root, means in this case : MailConfiguration.

Am I right if I consider that immutable objects should never be in an uncohesive state ? Thus, would validation in constructor as I made be preferred in the concerned entity (and so avoiding aggregate to worry about validation of it's "children" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I follow you 100%, but one way to handle ensuring immutable objects are only allowed to be created if they are valid is to use the [Essence Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7349/The-Essence-Pattern-in-C).

In a nutshell, the idea is that the parent class contains a static factory that creates immutable instances of itself based on instances of an inner "essence" class. The inner essence is mutable and allows objects to be built up, so you can put the pieces together as you go, and can be validated along the way as well.

The SOLID principals and good DDD is abided by since the parent immutable class is still doing only one thing, but allows others to build it up through it's "essence".

For an example of this, check out the [Ldap extension](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/LdapUserDetailsImpl.Essence.html) to the Spring Security library.

Comment: Thanks :) I read your article and especially this more detailed one : http://hillside.net/plop/plop98/final_submissions/P10.pdf

Comment: Yes, I linked to the one I did since it's a more practical example and also linked to the source article on the pattern.

Comment: And in my case where MailConfiguration wraps AddressesPart. Does it make sense to put an AddressPartEssence inside AddressesPart and MailConfigurationEssence inside MailConfiguration ? Or just into AddressesPart enough to avoid an  overcomplicated solution ?

Comment: @Mik378 - You would want one essence inside each immutable class, in general. So, in your case, since it seems that `MailConfiguration` is mutable, you would not see much benefit from using the essence pattern there, but I would definitely do it with the `AddressPart`.

Answer (score 5):

There's a basic pattern in DDD that perfectly does the job of checking and assembling objects to create a new one : the [Factory](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/110).

> I've read in some articles than in respect of DDD, all validations
>   must be present and only present in Aggregate Root

I strongly disagree with that. There can be validation logic in a wide range of places in DDD :

- Validation upon creation, performed by a Factory
- Enforcement of an aggregate's invariants, usually done in the Aggregate Root
- Validation spanning accross several objects can be found in Domain Services.
- etc.

Also, I find it funny that you bothered to create an AddressesPart value object -which is a good thing, without considering making EMailAddress a value object in the first place. I think it complicates your code quite a bit because there's no encapsulated notion of what an email address is, so AddressesPart (and any object that will manipulate addresses for that matter) is forced to deal with the AddressValidator to perform validation of its addresses. I think it shouldn't be its responsibility but that of an AddressFactory.

Answer (score 1):

Some observations first.

Why no generics? J2SE5.0 came out in 2004.

Current version of Java SE has `Objects.requiresNonNull` as standard. Bit of a mouthful and the capitalisation is wrong. Also returns the passed object so doesn't need a separate line.

```
    this.senderAddress = requiresNonNull(senderAddress);
```

Your classes are not quite immutable. They are subclassable. Also they don't make a safe copy of their mutable arguments (`Set`s - shame there aren't immutable collection types in the Java  library yet). Note, copy before validation.

```
    this.recipientToMailAddresses = validate(new HashSet<String>(
        recipientToMailAddresses
    ));
```

The use of `^` and `$` in the regex is a little misleading.

If the validation varies, then there's two obvious (sane) choices:

- Only do the widest variation in this class. Validate more specifically in the context it is going to be used.
- Pass in the validator used and have this as a property. To be useful, client code would have to check and do something reasonable with this information, which is unlikely.

It doesn't make a lot of sense to pass the validator into the constructor and then discard it. That's making the constructor overcomplicated. Put it in a static method, if you must.

The enclosing instance should check that its argument are valid for that particular use, but should not overlap with classes ensuring that they are generally valid. Where would it end?

Comment: Thanks for these observations :) I'm constrained to use JDK 1.4 since I work for an application in an investment bank which is still in 1.4 ...  You said that putting validator in constructor parameter of value object would be overcomplicated, but with a static method, an object could really be instanciated and used with a ...null validator ? dangerous if creation isn't atomic no? Perhaps I don't well take your approach, could you make a brief example ?

Comment: 1.4 was replaced seven or eight years ago. I bet their job ads ask for cutting-edge skills and then list technologies from the 1990s. If you use a static creation method, you can do validation before the object is even constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Although an old question but for anyone stumbling upon the subject matter, please keep it simple with POJOs (Plain Old Java Objects).
As for validations, there is no single truth because for a pure DDD you need to keep the context always in mind.
For example a user with no credit card data can and should be allowed to create an account. But credit card data is needed when checking out on some shopping basket page. 
How this is beautifully solved by DDD is by moving the bits and pieces of code to the Entities and Value Objects where it naturally belong.

As a second example, if address should never be empty in the context of a domain level task, then Address value object should force this assertion inside the object instead of using asking a third party library to check if a certain value object is null or not.

Moreover Address as a standalone value object doesn't convey much at its own when compared with ShippingAddress, HomeAddress or CurrentResidentialAddress ... the ubiquitous language, in other words names convey their intent.